# how to use grep in R to get the specified character?

Tags: r, regex

I have

```
str=c("00005.profit", "00005.profit-in","00006.profit","00006.profit-in")
```

and I want to get

```
 "00005.profit"  "00006.profit"
```

How can I achieve this using `grep` in R?

Comment: 5 digits followed by `.profit`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
R> s <- c("00005.profit", "00005.profit-in","00006.profit","00006.profit-in")
> unique(gsub("([0-9]+.profit).*", "\\1", s))
[1] "00005.profit" "00006.profit"
R>
```

We define a regular expression as digits followed by `.profit`, which we assign by keeping the expression in parantheses. The `\\1` then recalls the first such assignment -- and as we recall nothing else that is what we get. The `unique()` then reduces the four items to two unique ones.

Answer (score 4):

Dirk's answer is pretty much the ideal generalisable answer, but here are a couple of other options based on the fact that your example always has a `-` character starting the part you wish to chop off:

1: `gsub` to return everything prior to the `-`

```
gsub("(.+)-.+","\\1",str)
```

2: `strsplit` on `-` and keep only the first part.

```
sapply(strsplit(str,"-"),head,1)
```

Both return:

```
[1] "00005.profit" "00005.profit" "00006.profit" "00006.profit"
```

which you can then wrap in `unique` to not return duplicates like:

```
unique(gsub("(.+)-.+","\\1",str))
unique(sapply(strsplit(str,"-"),head,1))
```

These will then return:

```
[1] "00005.profit" "00006.profit"
```

Another non-generalisable solution would be to just take the first 12 characters (assuming string length for the part you want to keep doesn't change):

```
unique(substr(str,1,12))
[1] "00005.profit" "00006.profit"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually interpreting your question differently.  I think you *might* want

```
grep("[0-9]+\\.profit$",str,value=TRUE)
```

That is, if you only want the strings that *end* with `profit`. The `$` special character stands for "end of string", so it excludes cases that have additional characters at the end ... The `\\.` means "I really want to match a dot, not any character at all" (a `.` by itself would match any character).  You weren't entirely clear about your target pattern -- you might prefer `"0+[1-9]\\.profit$"` (any number of zeros followed by a single non-zero digit), or even `"0{4}[1-9]\\.profit$"` (4 zeros followed by a single non-zero digit).